# MsTest - Mocking a DbContext with DbContextOption and configuration

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, mocking, moq, ioc-container

I have 2 project, Data and Data.test, I use ef core and .net core for both of them, for Data project I have ExpenseDb like this:

```
 public class ExpenseDb: DbContext 
{
    private IConfigurationRoot _config;
    public ExpenseDb(DbContextOptions<ExpenseDb> options, IConfigurationRoot config) : base(options)
    {
        _config = config;


    }


    public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config["Data:ConnectionString"]);
    }


}
```

And I have a repository for Account like this:

```
  private ExpenseDb _db;

    public AccountRepository(ExpenseDb db)
    {
        _db = db;

    }


    public IEnumerable<Account> All(Guid userId)
    {
        return (_db.Accounts.AsNoTracking().Where(a => a.UserId == userId).ToList());
    }
```

I use ms IOC for injectiong dependencies like this :

```
 public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json");

        _config = builder.Build();
    }

    IConfigurationRoot _config;

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(_config);


        services.AddDbContext<ExpenseDb>(ServiceLifetime.Scoped);


    }
```

These all are in my Data project, and for Data.Test I would like to test All method, I realized I must Mock my ExpenseDb so I got Moq from Nuget Package and now I have test class like this :

```
 [TestClass]
public class AccountRepositoryTest
{

    private readonly Mock<ExpenseDb> _dbMock = new Mock<ExpenseDb>();
    private readonly AccountRepository _repo;



    public AccountRepositoryTest()
    {
        _repo = new AccountRepository(_dbMock.Object);
    }


    [TestMethod]
    public void AllForInvalidUser()
    {
        var fakeaccount = new Account() { Name="cat2",OpenDate=DateTime.Now,StartBalance=100};
        Mock < DbSet < Account >> acMock = DbSetMock.Create(fakeaccount);
        var results = _repo.All(Guid.Parse("cf15c6c9-f688-47ee-892e-297e530be053"));
        Assert.IsNotNull(results);

    }

}
```

Obviously my test is failed, because I must pass config and options to my ExpenseDb somehow, but I don't know How?!

I searched and I found out all answer are saying "You must have an inteface for your service" but i don't want to create an unnecessary interface.

Comment: Tightly coupling your code to implementation concerns is making the code difficult to test. abstract those concerns so that they can be mocked/replaced during unit tests. This will make the code more flexible. If you do not want to add interfaces then not much else can be done with regards to unit tests. You could look into using in memory database for integration tests.

Answer (score 0):

Since DbContextOptions and config are not being used in the actual test code. You could create a constructor in your db context marked as protected to allow the instantiation of the ExpenseDb object without any params.